# Express server doesn't start

Tags: reactjs, express

When I run my node server, nothing happens and it doesn't show any errors:

[image: Click here to look at my command line]

**Node Server**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
// const router = require('./router')

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist/')))

// app.use('/api', router)

app.get('*', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist/index.html'))
})
```

This is my folder hierarchy:

[image: This is my folder hierarchy]

Comment: Where is the call to `listen`?

Answer (score 1):

You have initialised the express server but you need to bind the connection to a port and then listen for requests.

Add the following to the entry point of your Node server:

```
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on PORT ${PORT}`));
```